# Как сделать сортировку при помощи JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можно ли при помощи JS реализовать такое:
Есть на странице несколько блоков, допустим это товар в интернет магазине. И нужно сделать сортировку, есть три категории, Телефоны, Планшеты, Телефоны-планшеты, Нужно что бы при нажатии на "Телефоны" выводились только блоки с телефонами, а при нажатии например на "Телефоны-планшеты" выводились и телефоны и планшеты. Как можно реализовать?

Т.е. один товар может находится в нескольких категориях.

Comment: Можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на "телефоны" выводились только телефоны, а при нажатии на "Телфоны-планшеты" выводились и телефоны, и планшеты. Если серьезно, то в мире магии нет, чтобы хоть как-то помочь, покажите хоть что-то (!!!!!!), что у вас сейчас есть.

Comment: @Alexxosipov, я спросил реально ли это с помощью JS реализовать

Comment: Да, реально. Только вы спросили "Как можно реализовать?" (см. ваш вопрос). Я и ответил.

Comment: Более чем реально, если у вас фронт написан на реакте или вью

Comment: @DiDex на ванильном/jquery тоже спокойно делается же

Answer (score 1):

Пример кода:

```js
var content = $('.content');

$('button[data-filter]').on('click', (e)=>
{
  var filter = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-filter');
  $('li', content).show();
  if (filter) $('li:not(.' + filter.split(' ').join(', .') + ')', content).hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  <button data-filter="phone">Телефоны</button>
  <button data-filter="tab">Планшеты</button>
  <button data-filter="phone tab">Телефоны и планшеты</button>
</div>
<ul class="content">
  <li class="product phone">Телефон</li>
  <li class="product phone">Телефон</li>
  <li class="product tab">Планшет</li>
  <li class="product phone tab">Планшет и телефон</li>
  <li class="product tab">Планшет</li>
  <li class="product tab phone">Планшет и телефон</li>
  <li class="product phone">Телефон</li>
  <li class="product tab">Планшет</li>
  <li class="product tab">Планшет</li>
  <li class="product phone">Телефон</li>
</ul>
```